# Mobile apps unable to communicate with API

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, ios-app, api

When browsing through the Stack Exchange mobile apps, I get an error message. There seems to be a problem with the API.

[image]

It seems https://api.stackexchange.com/ is down so it might be solved soon.

Comment: Confirmed: API is down. We're investigating...

Comment: Unrelated issue, but whenever I tap any of the links after opening the app (the ones that cover most of the screen), it always says "Loading the question failed".

Comment: Naw, that's totally the same issue. Seems up now?

Comment: Bad commit caused an assembly conflict that didn't show up in local / test environments. Rollback fixed the issue for now.